# Shortest possible sequence to get to a number

Tags: algorithm, performance

The first element of the sequence is `1`.
i.e. `A[0]=1`
`A[i+1]` can either be `2A[i]` or `A[i]+1`.

We have to find the shortest possible sequence.

e.g.:

```
If N is 18
 A[0]=1, A[1]=2,4,8,9,18
```

So my code was basically.

```
 int count = 0;
 for (int i = N, i != 1;){
 if (i % 2 == 0) { 
     i /= 2;
     ++count;
 } else{
     --i;
     ++count;
 }
 return count;
```

As you can see, this algorithm is pretty straightforward and will return the shortest length. However, the worst time complexity is `O(N)`

Is there any way to do it so that it is `O(logN)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is already O(log(N)). To see this, your algorithm can be rewritten like this:

```
 int count = 0;
 for (int i = N; i != 1;) {
   if (i % 2 == 1) { 
     --i
     ++count;
   }
   i /= 2;
   ++count;
 }
 return count;
```

For each bit, you are either dividing by two, or subtracting one and dividing by two. Since the number of operations you do per bit does not depend on the size of N, the time is O(log(N)).

### Some details on why this works

If you think in terms of binary.  Multiplying by two is shifting the bits left one.  Adding one is setting the right-most bit to one.  So you can find the sequence of operations just by reading off the binary value of N.

N=18 is 10010 in binary, so we have

```
1 = starting value:            1
0 = multiply by 2 :            2
0 = multiply by 2 :            4
1 = multiply by 2 and add one: 8,9
0 = multiply by 2 :            18
```

The solution isn't necessarily unique, but it is always at least as short as any other solution.  To see why, you just need to observe that adding one two times in a row is equivalent to adding one to bit 1 and zeroing out bit 0:

```
xxx01 -> xxx10
```

But you could have gotten the same result by adding one previously instead, so there is no advantage to adding one twice in a row.  Therefore, an optimal sequence of operations consists of repeatedly multiplying by two and optionally adding one between each multiplication.